# Trying to install PHP 5.2 on IIS/Win 2008 - Error 500

Tags: windows-server-2008, php, iis-7.5

I have a fresh install of IIS 7 - I just added Web Platform Installer, and PHP 5.2 thru that.
However, when trying to access to a simple test.php file (just has phpinfo() in it), I get the following list of errors:

```
• IIS was not able to access the web.config file for the Web site or application.
  This can occur if the NTFS permissions are set incorrectly.
• IIS was not able to process configuration for the Web site or application.
• The authenticated user does not have permission to use this DLL.
• The request is mapped to a managed handler but the .NET Extensibility Feature
  is not installed.
```

The domain was created with dot net panel, but I don't think that has to do with this problem, unless maybe it uses a specific user?
Is it possible that there's an issue with permissions?
Maybe I need to add php thruough dot net panel?

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a misconfiguration on my side. Under "Handler Mappings" I added a php handler that was local to a website, when it was setup already to webserver level.
After deleting the local handler, I could see the phpinfo() output.